# SoapUI Startup Crash

Tags: windows, java, batch-file, crash

Computer Specs:
Win 7 Pro x64
8GB memory

SoapUI version 5.3.0 w/out built in browser
Java version 8.121

Whenever I start SoapUI the splash screen will come up and then load SoapUI. It'll give me the prompt asking if I want to "Stay in the Loop" .. I click skip and then a few seconds later the app crashes. The crash "Java Platform SE binary has stopped working" comes up and I close out of the app. I've checked to make sure this wasn't memory related. I don't seem to be running out of memory. I make sure no other apps are running when I've been trying to get this to work.

When I run the soapui.bat I get the message saying JAVA_HOME is not set. Can someone tell me where in the code I need to set this? I've attached a snippet of the soapui.bat. I'm not a developer/programmer. I'm trying to help someone within our company.

I've also tried installing 5.3.0 with the built in browser and the same thing happens. It'll open and then crash.

I'd really appreciate any help. I've been beating my head against this for days.

I have java saved at path c:\jdk1.8.121

How would I set java_home in this .bat script properly?

Thank you for the help.

```
*@echo off
set SOAPUI_HOME=%~dp0
if exist "%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin" goto SET_BUNDLED_JAVA
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%" goto SET_SYSTEM_JAVA
echo JAVA_HOME is not set, unexpected results may occur.
echo Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
goto SET_SYSTEM_JAVA
:SET_BUNDLED_JAVA
set JAVA=%SOAPUI_HOME%..\jre\bin\java
goto END_SETTING_JAVA
:SET_SYSTEM_JAVA
set JAVA=java
:END_SETTING_JAVA
rem init classpath
set OLDDIR=%CD%
cd /d %SOAPUI_HOME%
set CLASSPATH=%SOAPUI_HOME%soapui-5.3.0.jar;%SOAPUI_HOME%..\lib\*
"%JAVA%" -cp "%CLASSPATH%" com.eviware.soapui.tools.JfxrtLocator > %TEMP%\jfxrtpath
set /P JFXRTPATH= < %TEMP%\jfxrtpath
del %TEMP%\jfxrtpath
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%JFXRTPATH%
rem JVM parameters, modify as appropriate
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -Dsoapui.properties=soapui.properties "-Dsoapui.home=%SOAPUI_HOME%\" -splash:SoapUI-Spashscreen.png
if "%SOAPUI_HOME%" == "" goto START
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.ext.libraries="%SOAPUI_HOME%ext"
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.ext.listeners="%SOAPUI_HOME%listeners"
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.ext.actions="%SOAPUI_HOME%actions"
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.library.path="%SOAPUI_HOME%\"
    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dwsi.dir="%SOAPUI_HOME%..\wsi-test-tools"
rem uncomment to disable browser component
rem    set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.browser.disabled="true"
:START
rem ********* run soapui ***********
"%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI %*
cd /d %OLDDIR%*
```

Comment: I have added JAVA_HOME in my system enviroment to c:\jre1.8.121. This is the install path of my Java runtime enviroment but when i run the .bat it still shows it loading the 1.7.0_55 built in java enviroment. How do I disable the built in Java?